issues with MoveIt: Attached body "object" not found, IK failed
I'm new to ROS and the MoveIt world so i hope this question doesn't sound too much silly.
I'm trying to execute a pick and place operation using MoveIt with the Franka Emika Panda robot. To do so, i'm trying to execute the following node (that i found in MoveIt tutorials):https://github.com/moveit/moveit_tutorials/blob/kinetic-devel/doc/pick_place/src/pick_place_tutorial.cpp . When i run the node I can correctly visualize the robot, the two tables and the object in Rviz, but the robot remains stationary and does not execute the planned trajectory, and i receive a bunch of errors. I believe the problem is not the node, neither the panda model i'm using on Moveit ( copied this repository: https://github.com/moveit/panda_moveit_config) .  Below are the errors I receive from the terminals.
from moveit terminal: [ INFO] [1719928607.215872451]: IK failed [ INFO] [1719928607.215885656]: Sampler failed to produce a state [ INFO] [1719928607.215894997]: Manipulation plan 0 failed at stage 'reachable & valid pose filter' on thread 2 [ INFO] [1719928607.216068059]: Pickup planning completed after 0.114128 seconds [ INFO] [1719928608.299719480]: Planning attempt 1 of at most 1 [ERROR] [1719928608.299968336]: Attached body 'object' not found
from node execution terminal: [ WARN] [1719928607.216441565]: Fail: ABORTED: No motion plan found. No execution attempted. [ WARN] [1719928608.300568273]: Fail: ABORTED: Invalid group in motion plan request
my questions are:

What could cause the inverse kinematics to fail ?

Why am I receiving the error "Attached body 'object' not found" even though I have added the object to the scene?

how can i solve the error "Invalid group in motion plan request"?


Any suggestions or guidance on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated:)
Thank you in advance for your help!
